# Pokemon GO did not level up from 26 to 27

Tags: pokemon-go

I was on level 26 and when I had accumulated enough XP the graphic popped up to show I had leveled up But it said level 26 again. What happened? It says I have to earn 200000 XP which is the amount needed for Level 27. It shows I have earned 900347XP which validates I have surpassed the amount for level 26. VERY unhappy. Please help.

Comment: Did you get the animation of levelling up, it takes a while sometimes ...

Comment: Best way to help is to say you to open a ticket with Niantic.

Comment: 900347 XP is enough for level 26, not level 27.

Answer (score 3):

https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/4s1cpq/xp_requirements_for_levels_so_far_125/

```
lvl -  XP REQ.  - Total XP
[...]
25  -  150,000  - 710,000   

26  -  190,000  - 900,000

27  -  200,000  - 1,100,000 
[...]
```

According to this website, you needed 900,000 XP to **get to** level 26. According to what you posted, you have 900,347, which means you were level 25 and got to level 26 just as intended.